# Opensuse 13.2 hybrid graphics cards Nvidia/Intel driver installation

Tags: nvidia-geforce, gnome3, display-driver, opensuse-13.2

I have a laptop with hybrid graphics cards as you can see from `lspci`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
```

I've tried installing Nvidia drivers following official documentation from Opensuse, in all possible ways: 1-click install, repository, and the hard way. But I always end up with `Oh no! Something has gone wrong` error from Gnome.

Gnome version: 3.14.0

Nvidia driver: GF8

Does Opensuse support hybrid graphics cards? Please provide any guidance as I don't know where to start debugging this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was another driver for hybrid graphics cards. To install it follow the following procedures:

https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:NVIDIA_Bumblebee